# Writing a function to split data into training and testing - weird error

Tags: r

Night be a nooby post but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this function. Essentially, the idea was to write a single function that could output two new data frames (one with testing and one with training data), however I encountered a problem with that the function can only output one dataframe at a time so instead I attempted to use IF commands.

This was what I came up with.

```
split <- function(df, tr.split, option) { 
set.seed(1337)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(df), replace = TRUE, prob = c(tr.split, 1-tr.split))
if(option=="TEST") {te.data <- df[ind==2,]}
if(option=="TEST") {te.data}
if(option=="TRAIN") {tr.data <- df[ind==1,]}
if(option=="TRAIN") {tr.data}}
```

Instead when the function is ran with my data set it returns an empty dataset. 
It was run like this.

```
te <- split(cleaned.data, 0.8, "TEST")
tr <- split(cleaned.data, 0.8, "TRAIN")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Change `if(option=="TEST") {te.data}` to `if(option=="TEST") {return(te.data)}` and the same for the last line of the function. Of course, this is still unnecessarily complicated. You could just use  `if(option=="TEST") return(df[ind==2,])`

Comment: @Roland - Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

This function provide a list of two elements, the first is the training set, the second the test set:

```
split <- function(df, tr.split) { 
  set.seed(1337)
  ind <- sample(2, nrow(df), replace = TRUE, prob = c(tr.split, 1-tr.split))
  te.data <- df[ind==2,]
  tr.data <- df[ind==1,]

  return(list(tr.data,te.data))
  }
```

An example:

```
df<-data.frame(x=c(1:20)+round(runif(20,min = 5, max=20),0),
+                date=seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 20))
> split(df,0.8)
[[1]]
    x       date
1  19 2000-01-01
2  18 2000-01-02
3   9 2000-01-03
4  11 2000-01-04
5  18 2000-01-05
6  26 2000-01-06
8  26 2000-01-08
9  21 2000-01-09
10 30 2000-01-10
14 22 2000-01-14
16 31 2000-01-16
19 28 2000-01-19
20 28 2000-01-20

[[2]]
    x       date
7  26 2000-01-07
11 29 2000-01-11
12 19 2000-01-12
13 29 2000-01-13
15 32 2000-01-15
17 37 2000-01-17
18 34 2000-01-18
```